# Programming for hybrid models of arima-ann and arima-svm time series foercasting in rstudio

Tags: r, neural-networks, forecasting, svm

i am doing my mphil thesis on hybrid modeling of arima-ann and arima-svm for time series forecasting following the G.Peter Zhang's research paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231201007020). i will use data set of inflation, stock prices and exchange rate for my analysis and will compare their results which technique do better. please if anyone has programming or codes for r studio then please share with me (rizwanali_16@pide.edu.pk). i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/344096/89649

Comment: i already know about this link but this is not what i want. i have seen a lot of paper on hybrid modeling and they are actually doing well.

Comment: can you point me to some of those papers? I'm curious about them.

Comment: Babu, C. N., & Reddy, B. E. (2014). A moving-average filter based hybrid ARIMA–ANN model for forecasting time series data. Applied Soft Computing, 23, 27-38.

Comment: 2. Chen, K. Y., & Wang, C. H. (2007). A hybrid SARIMA and support vector machines in forecasting the production values of the machinery industry in Taiwan. Expert Systems with Applications, 32(1), 254-264.

Comment: Pai, P. F., & Lin, C. S. (2005). A hybrid ARIMA and support vector machines model in stock price forecasting. Omega, 33(6), 497-505

Comment: Kumar, M., & Thenmozhi, M. (2014). Forecasting stock index returns using ARIMA-SVM, ARIMA-ANN, and ARIMA-random forest hybrid models. International Journal of Banking, Accounting and Finance, 5(3), 284-308.                                                                                         
                 sir Skander H.  these are some of them. i defended my thesis proposal on this topic but unfortunately i am not good in machine learning and programming that's why i am feeling difficulty if you can help me in rstudio then i will be thankful. if you want other papers i will provide you.

Comment: I can help you in a few days. For now I recommend looking on Github.